# remove all image take options (alt, class, styling etc) from its tag

Tags: php, html, css, image, str-replace

i have a website where people can copy and paste directly from the page into mine. This then gets saved into my DB.

Currently, i had only planned for users to use my image insert tool which would save an image as a basic html image tag:

```
  <img src="www.linktomimage.com"/>
```

or copy from the edit view of a forum which would place the image into a BB tag:

```
  [img]www.linktoimage.com[/img]
```

When echoing out this data, i would use str replace to change any BBcode [img] tags to html image tags so that they could be displayed correctly.

However, i know realise that users may copy directly from the page and there for the image tag could be wrapped in all sorts of tags.

2 comparisons:

```
  <img src="http://AN IMAGE LINK URL" border="0" alt="" />
```

And:

```
 <img class='bbc_img' src="http://AN IMAGE LINK URL">
```

Lots of different forums use various versions.

My question is how can i remove everything from those image links and then put the url into my own:

```
  <img class="buildimage" src="http://my image">
```

I cant think of a way to do it with str_replace() as there are too many different variations.

Hope this makes sense.

For reference, i currently use this for changing the [img] tags to html and adding my class:

```
    $text = str_replace("[IMG]", "<img class='buildimage' src='", "$text");
$text = str_replace("[/IMG]", "'>", "$text");
```

Thanks! Craig.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript on the page with the input to remove all attributes except for src?

Comment: You could use a DOM parser, get the attributes you want and build a new image tag with just these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to grab the src from the string:

```
$string = '<img border="0" src="/images/sampleimage.jpg" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />';

preg_match('/<img(.*)src(.*)=(.*)"(.*)"/U', $string, $result);

$foo = array_pop($result);
```